# What are the trim settings on ferried aircraft?

Tags: space-shuttle, aircraft-operations

Sometimes an aircraft or spacecraft is ferried on top of a carrier aircraft. Do these "piggy back riders" have their flight surfaces controlled (possibly remotely) during the flight? If not, how are they trimmed?

[image: Endeavour hitching a ride]
[image: Buran hitching a ride]

Comment: I suspect the only reason why that works is that the Space Shuttle flies and steers like a brick. It's normal turn radius is 22 nm. I expect severe control problems if you tried to carry a 737 on top of something.

Comment: Has this ever been done on something other than the space shuttle?

Comment: @Ben [Although not ferrying, the Air Force used to air-launch all the time](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/340450main_E51-593_full.jpg) testing things like the Bell X-1/X-2. Most aircraft though are usually under-slung instead of piggy-backed mostly because they are meant to be launched in flight. I haven't heard of one being ferried though, Airbus and Boeing have aircraft specifically to haul parts of airliners internally.

Comment: Some information in [Could the Shuttle Carrier Aircraft do a transatlantic flight with a Space Shuttle orbiter on its back?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23801/3201)

Comment: @RonBeyer - as I recall, the shuttle was air-launched as well for glide testing. A sort-of "throw" maneuver where the shuttle was released at the top of a climb and the 747 made a steepish dive to get out of the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of the [Short Mayo Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Mayo_Composite), controls of the payload aircraft were locked in neutral position until separation from the carrying aircraft in the air.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. The related wikipedia article even mentions the Space Shuttle ferrying.